# c++ - Lambda length of Linked List

Tags: c++, lambda, linked-list

Consider the following definition for the node of a Linked List:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

I am new to c++ and coming from functional programming. I wish to write a lambda to compute the length of a linked list.
I wrote:

```
auto listLength = [](Node * list){
    if(list == NULL) return 0;
    else return 1 + listLength(list -> next);
};

error: variable 'lengthList' declared with 'auto' type cannot appear in its own initializer
```

If I change from *auto* to *int* I get:

```
 error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
```

What is the issue?

Comment: `lengthList` is incongruent with `listLength`, are you sure you are showing the relevant code here?

Comment: The question is correct. But I would recommend you to replace recursion to the `while` loop. It is more safe and faster. And replace `NULL` to `nullptr` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is twofold:

1) A lambda needs to capture any object that's defined outside of the lambda.

2) The definition of `listLength` isn't complete until the end of the entire variable declaration.

It's sort of a chicken-vs-egg problem. The cleanest solution is to use `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>

std::function< int (Node *)> listLength;

listLength = [&](Node * list){
    if(list == NULL) return 0;
    else return 1 + listLength(list -> next);
};
```

Comment: where can I find documentation and/or explanation about this?

Comment: This is C++11, so any C++ book that's been updated to at least the C++11 standard.

Comment: When you make a declaration "type name=value", the "name" part isn't defined until ***after*** this declaration. Your initial attempt tried to use "listlength" before it was actually defined. That was one of the problems with your initial approach.

Comment: @P0W I had already found that but it does not actually explain the use of the capturing function std::function

Comment: I am using " a Tour of C++" but the capturing std::function is not explained there

Comment: Capturing refers to the lambda itself. In order for the lambda to use any object that's not declared by the lambda itself, it must be captured. "listlength" is an object declared outside of the body of the lambda itself, hence it must be captured, in order for it to be used inside the body of the lambda.